# Как сделать чтобы при hover изображение оставалось на месте

Tags: css3, css

Есть изображение 200*200
задаем радиус 100px - получаем круг + обрамляем border 2px (увеличиваем радиус +1px)
При наведении на изображение border увеливаеться до 4px

```
img{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 border-radius: 101px;
}
img:hover{ 
 border: 4px solid #00f;
 border-radius: 102px;
}
```

При этом изображение не статично, отсюда вопрос как сделать чтобы при hover изображение оставалось на месте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а вы делайте не `border`, а `outline`.

Либо иной вариант: `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: outline не умеет быть скругленным

Comment: точно. Прошу прощения за введение в заблуждение.
Но вариант с border-box остаётся.

Comment: -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Для Firefox */  
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Ширина блока с полями */

это работает!